# Change target of .find from tr:has(th) so it looks for the div

Tags: jquery

I'm using code from (http://bl.ocks.org/kalebdf/ee7a5e7f44416b2116c0) in order to download an html table to csv. I've used others but they don't work on IE. the one from the link above does work on IE.

The issue I'm having is that my table is generated with the column headings in divs -   column heading

When I download the table ot csv the table row data for the  is included in the csv but the column headings are missing.

I'm assuming that the reason is since they are in divs. The part of the js file creates a variable for the headings and rows.

```
    var $headers = $table.find('tr:has(th)'),
        $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)')
```

My question is: How can I change the tr:has(th) so it finds the text in the div?

Comment: *finds the text in the div* - in which div?

Comment: Show a sample for the HTML markup of those headings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the headers `div` are within `th`...

Like:

```
<tr>
  <th>
    <div>blah</div>
  </th>
  <th>
    <div>blah-blah</div>
  </th>
</tr>
```

Try to change the `grabRow` function to this:

```
function grabRow(i,row){

    var $row = $(row);
    //for some reason $cols = $row.find('td') || $row.find('th') won't work...
    var $cols = $row.find('td');
    if(!$cols.length) $cols = $row.find('div');  // Change th for div on this line

    return $cols.map(grabCol)
                .get().join(tmpColDelim);
}
```